# Spark SQL: Parse date string from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use spark SQL or pyspark to reformat a date field from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'yyyy/mm/dd'. The field type is string:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]")\
    .appName("date.com")\
    .getOrCreate()

my_df = spark.createDataFrame(["13/04/2020", "16/04/2020", "19/04/2020"], StringType()).toDF("date")
expected_df = spark.createDataFrame(["2020/04/12", "2020/04/16", "2020/04/19"], StringType()).toDF("date")
```

I have tried the following spark sql command, but this returns the date as literally 'yyyy/MM/dd' rather than '2020/04/12'.

```sql
select date_format(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'yyyy/MM/dd' as reformatted_date
FROM my_df
```

I have also looked at the following documentation but didn't see anything that fits my scenario: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

If it's not possible in spark sql then pyspark would work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert to date type using `to_date` first:

```
select date_format(to_date(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'yyyy/MM/dd') as reformatted_date
from my_df
```

Answer (score 0):

df1.select( to_date(date_format(to_date(lit("12/12/2020"), "dd/MM/yyyy"), "yyyy-MM-dd") ).as("campo")).show()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).